# Mongoose find-by-reference returns nothing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is data from the mongo client:

```
> db.projects.find({ })[1];
{
    "name" : "App 276",
    "slug" : "app276",
    "createdByUser" : ObjectId("52f20518b66ae3622c000002"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fc91f508e3507c19000002"),
    "screens" : [ ],
    "dateUpdated" : ISODate("2014-02-13T09:34:23.102Z"),
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2014-02-13T09:34:23.102Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

This is my server code:

```
/** List Projects */
exports.list = function(req, res) {
    console.log('list', mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userId));
    return Project.find({ createdByUser: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userId) }, function (err, projects) {
        if (!err) {
            return res.json(projects);
        }
        else {
            return res.send(err);
        }
    });
};
```

and this is my server output:

```
list 52fc9720b85bac3c1a000002
GET /api/projects 200 42ms - 2b
```

The JSON output is an empty array - why?

Comment: `52f20518b66ae3622c000002`<>`52fc9720b85bac3c1a000002`...?

Comment: Doh! I turned out the parameter was actually in `req.query.userId`, and `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(null)` generated a value that looked credible. Need more coffee! Or less. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requested project created by user `52f **c9720b85bac3c1a** 000002`.
Your database extract seems to contain a project by user `52f **20518b66ae3622c** 000002`

Have you tried with the right id ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Mongoose Population. It's better use this feature in this case. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html